# Not printing desired output for sieve of eratosthene

Tags: c, printf, sieve-of-eratosthenes, sieve

I'm trying to create a program which outputs the list of prime numbers given an input value, n.

The SieveEratosthenes function that I made: 
- generates a list of primes over the first n integers
- creates storage for the list of generated primes 
- returns the number of primes generated.

Here's the code in my main function:

```
int main(){
    int n, i;
    int *primes;

    printf("Number that needs to be prime factorized: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int num_primes;

    num_primes = SieveEratosthenes(n, &primes);
    printf("Generated a list of %d primes\n", num_primes);
    printf("\n");

    for (i = 0; i <= sizeof(num_primes) + 1; i++){
        printf("%d", *primes++);
    }
   printf("\n");

   return 0;
}
```

Say n = 20; 
My output is:

'Generated a list of 8 primes

2 3 5 7 11 13'

When my desired output should be '2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19'

My sieve function is working correctly, but I cannot get to print out the entire list of prime numbers in my main function though.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'd suggest `primes[i]` instead of `*primes++`. This way you preserve the pointer to the original array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot determine the number of primes by computing `sizeof(num_primes)`: that's a compile-time constant, it does not change with the value that you put in `num_primes`. It looks like your system uses four bytes for an `int`, so iterating from zero to sizeof+1, inclusive, covers indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, and 5, which is consistent with your observation that six numbers get printed.

If `SieveEratosthenes` returns the number of primes that it found, your loop should iterate from zero to that number, not to `sizeof(num_primes)`:

```
for (i = 0; i != num_primes ; i++){
    printf("%d", primes[i]);
}
```

Note that I changed `*primes++` to `primes[i]`. This is to help you free `primes` when you are done, and avoid a memory leak.